# Executing async tasks when second dependent on first

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need some help regarding asynchronous programming. For simplicity, consider a list of integers 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5

I have two async tasks. One to get record and other to create record. I only want to create a record if the id property does not exist yet.

```
 public async Task<Record> GetRecord(int id)
 {
   var client = new HttpClient();
   // build request
   // var response = await client.SendAsync(request); // sending to 3rd party vendor
   // depending on response, return the Record object or null
 }

 public async Task<bool> CreateRecord(int id)
 {
   var client = new HttpClient();
   // build request
   // var response = await client.SendAsync(request); // sending to 3rd party vendor
   // depending on response, return true or false
 }
```

Main program

```
foreach(var id in IDs)
{
  var record = await GetRecord(id); ?? How can I wait here 
  if (record == null)
     await CreateRecord(id)
}
```

For some reason, this program is creating records with 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5. It should not be creating a duplicate record with id 3.

I also tried the following but it also creates duplicate records

```
 var record = Task.Run( async => await GetRecord(id)).Result
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hmm One thing that can comes to my mind is limiting the threads using  `SemaphoreSlim` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0

Comment: of course there's other option such as using a Then +  Recursion approach too.

Comment: Based on the code you posted, your program should work as expected. Could you offer a reproducible example? Btw please take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient) guide, regarding the usage of the `HttpClient` class.

Comment: Hmm... your code looks ok the way it is.  May be something specific in your GetRecord call whereever it is implemented.  Possibly it is returning null when there is already an existing record with the given ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample I tried showing what you have should work fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSync
{
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Record(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
public class TestClass
{
    private List<Record> SavedRecords = new List<Record>();
    private List<int> Ids = new List<int>{1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2};
    private Random randome = new Random(8383838);
    public async Task Process()
    {
        foreach (var id in Ids)
        {
            var record = await GetRecord(id);

            if (record == null)
                await CreateRecord(id);
        }
    }

    public async Task<Record> GetRecord(int id)
    {
        await Task.Delay(randome.Next(100, 200));// simulate delay for a HttpClient kind of call
        return SavedRecords.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    }
    public async Task<bool> CreateRecord(int id)
    {
        await Task.Delay(randome.Next(200, 500));// simulate delay for a HttpClient kind of call
        SavedRecords.Add(new Record(id));
        return true;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (var record in SavedRecords)
            Console.WriteLine(record.Id);
    }
}
class Program
{

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating records!");

        var t = new TestClass();
        await t.Process();
        t.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("Done creating records!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Athadu, Thank you very much for your solution. I tried using the random delay line from your code and it seems to work. So may be the third party system is taking time to actually create record.